# Spring boot cucumber testing

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber

I try to perform some Cucumber tests of a Spring boot application.

It seems like Spring Boot is not started before tests are running.

What am i missing?

https://bitbucket.org/oakstair/spring-boot-cucumber-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Cucumber repo still runs without doing all the above steps:

https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Cucumber-spring-integration

Docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

To add more:

1. `@SpringBootTest` takes care of loading the application context in that case `@ContextConfiguration` is reductant.
2. Spring test automatically provides a bean of `TestRestTemplate` which can be autowired but still it should work with RestTemplate also.
3. It still runs without `RANDOM_PORT` but RANDOM port can be also used in conjunction for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a feature file, `feature1`, and `glueCode` in `org.xyz.feature1`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = "src/test/java/resources/feature/feature1",
    glue = {"org.xyz.feature1"})
public class CucumberTest {

}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class},
                webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration
@Ignore
@Transactional
public class FeatureTest extends CucumberTest {

  @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;

  @Given("........")
  public void test_1 {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and has updated the repo.

I did the following to get it working:

- Added `RANDOM_PORT` to `@SpringBootTest`
- Added `@ContextConfiguration`
- Switched from `RestTemplate` to `TestRestTemplate`